# AngularJs - Import Model in Component throwing error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm a beginner and hit a roadblock and need some quick help..

The error I'm receiving: [ts] Cannot find module './../../../Models/Property'.  It's seen by hovering over the import { Property } line

## In my property-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Property } from './../../../Models/Property';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-form',
  templateUrl: './property-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-form.component.css']
})
export class PropertyFormComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

## My folder structure

```
ClientApp
|___ app
   |___ components
      |___ property-form
         |___ property-form-component.css
         |___ property-form-component.html
         |___ property-form-component.ts
Models
|___ Property.cs
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?  Or how I can go about solving this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go one more level up on your import, like so:

`import { Property } from '../../../../Models/Property';`

With `../` you are on "components" folder level;

With `../../`, "app" folder;

With `../../../`, "ClientApp" folder;

With `../../../../` you are finally on the root folder, from which you can go to "Models".